# VB Access Update data type mismatch

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Sorry in advance, Im new to vb,

Im creating a small application for assignment as a MCQ quiz, Im using the same form but use the function of [nextques] proceed to next question and use [answer] to update the user answer to database(access).

I previously uses SQL Server and it work good but due to i need to run the application in school's computer where they wont allow me to install anything, I have no idea at all then decided to use access as it is easier to export and include it in debug file.

Ive go through some topics as well as did some changes however the problem persist. I set the [input] in access as integer, i did put parameter on it but it still not working.

ERROR code : Data type mismatch in criteria expression

```
Public Function answer(ans As Integer)
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=mom.mdb;"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        ' Update the answer 1234 (as abcd) according to id in lblnum.text
        Dim updatecmd As String = "UPDATE question SET [input] = @ans WHERE id = '" & lblnum.Text & "'"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", ans)
        cmd.CommandText = updatecmd
        updatecmd = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

        'Proceed to next question by calling Function NextQues
        nextques()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function
```

I tried also to make it like this however another error shows: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

```
Public Function answer(ans As Integer)
    Dim countid As Integer = 1
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=mom.mdb;"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        Dim updatecmd As String = "UPDATE question SET [input] = @ans WHERE id = @countid"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countid", countid)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", ans)
        cmd.CommandText = updatecmd
        updatecmd = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        countid = countid + 1
        con.Close()



        'Proceed to next question by calling Function NextQues
        nextques()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
Dim updatecmd As String = "UPDATE question SET [input] = @ans WHERE id = '" & lblnum.Text & "'"
```

to

```
Dim updatecmd As String = "UPDATE question SET [input] = @ans WHERE id = " & lblnum.Text
```

Comment: Integer values in sql statement don't have double quotes around them. Either single quote or nothing. Haven't tried your code but i think single quote will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me although i faced other bugs but most of them are caused by this problem haha thanks