# Fetching data to Excel VBA form from Access Database

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I have a database in Access and I want to enter some data from Excel VBA form into the database and also want to retrieve some data back into the form.

Sceenshot of the procedure is

[image]

This is the Add Button Code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connectionstring As String

Dim sql As String
connectionstring = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
connectionstring = connectionstring & "DATA Source=C:\Simple.accdb;"
con.Open connectionstring

sql = "insert into T1(ID,FName,Email)values('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "')"


con.Execute sql


MsgBox "Values Entered", vbInformation

con.Close
End Sub
```

Here is the Search Button Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
con.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Simple.accdb;"
'Open Db connection
con.Open
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open "Select * from T1 where ID= '" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & "'"
StartRow = 3
Do Until rs.EOF

'FName
UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = rs.Fields(1).Value
'Email
UserForm1.TextBox3.Text = rs.Fields(2).Value

rs.MoveNext
StartRow = StartRow + 1
Loop
Set rs = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

My problem is though I am able to add through the VBA form with ADD button, my search button code is not working. It says datatype mismatch in criteria expression.

All I wanted to do is perform a search on the basis of ID.

Please Help.

Comment: Please note if I change the sql query to **rs.Open "Select * from T1 "**  in the Search option, it is showing the last record in the table

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28249236/2127508) to a related question

Answer (score 2):

I think the ID field in your table is numeric - you need to remove the single quotes from around the criteria in your sql statement in the search button code.

Comment: Yes did that and it already worked. Thanks though for your help